# soql query to display records based on where condition

Tags: soql

SELECT BillingCountry FROM Account WHERE BillingCountry = 'india%'
Above is my query to display country whose value is india,thing i have 10 records whose country is india,executing above query,i got 10 country's whose value is 'India'. now i dnt want to display duplicate country.is it possible?!need help.Thanks in advance

Comment: use limit 1 (or) are you looking for district keyword

Comment: suppose if hav one more record with indiana,,if i use limit 1,indiana will not be shown.correct?!

Comment: You are querying the all Account objects that have BillingCountry set to 'India%'. This will return all Accounts that meet your Where clause (10 in your case). Your question does not make sense as you are requesting to prevent the display of duplicate countries? If it is a case where you only want one Account returned please apply a limit to your query.

Comment: conclusion,instead of taking list or set,we take list<aggregrate> then it will now show duplication.only one india value will be shown.

Answer (score 2):

To prevent the display of duplicates it is possible to store your query result within a collection type of Set.

```
Set<Account> accs = new Set<Account>([
    SELECT BillingCountry
    FROM Account
    WHERE BillingCountry = 'india%' 
]);

// From here you can use the set of Accounts which you will be sure there is no duplicates.
```

Take a look at [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_collections_sets.htm) link to understand the collection types within Apex.

Comment: i copy pasted your code,it is also displaying 10 recordds

Comment: This will return all Accounts with BillingCountry of India% but will assure you that there is no duplicates. Is it duplicates you are trying to prevent or do you wish to only return 1 Account with BillingCountry of India% ?

Comment: it is returning 10 recordfs

Comment: If you are looking to return 1 record please apply a limit to your query otherwise rephrase your question as you you have asked to prevent duplicates.

Comment: i think,id is also comparing.that is why iam getting id redcords

Answer (score 0):

Use a map to get the unique values.

```
List<Account> accList= [select BillingCountry from Account WHERE BillingCountry = 'india%'];

 Map<String,Account> accountMap  =new Map<String,Account>();

for(Account acc:accList){
    accountMap.put(acc.BillingCountry,acc);//This is map and hence it will always have unique values 
}
```

Comment: not working it is throwing all the 10 records

Comment: did you use accountMap.values()